# Magento Product Custom option value setPrice not working programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options, programmatically, option

I just don't get it. I have installed Magento 1.9.2.2 CE in my site.

But when I run following code as custom script from root directory, it doesn't set product custom option value price to my desired value, `$v->setPrice` is not working at all, while the other value functions do work, why is that ??

```
<?php
$magePath = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $magePath;
Varien_Profiler::enable();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product_ids  = array(897);
$productmodel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) {
    /**i use this two arrays for collecte value because i uses inside setData of 
    current option*/
    $cos     = array();
    $co      = array();
    $product = $productmodel->load($product_id);
    $options = $product->getProductOptionsCollection();
    if (isset($options)) {
        foreach ($options as $o) {
            $title = $o->getTitle();
            $optionType = $o->getType();
            //test type
            if ($optionType == "drop_down" && $title == "New Custom Title") {
                //getting collection of value related to current option
                $values = $o->getValuesCollection();
                $found  = false;
                foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
                    //test existing of value for update
                    if (1 == preg_match("/Ja$/i", $v->getTitle())) {
                        //update and save
                        $v->setTitle("Ja")->setSku("kk45")->setPriceType("fixed")->setSortOrder(2)->setPrice(floatval(120.0000));
                        $v->setOption($o)->save();
                        /**
                        this ligne is important i collecte all value required for normalize save function 
                        related to current option
                        */
                        $cos[] = $v->toArray($co);
                    }
                }
            }
            $o->setData("values", $cos)->save();
            //var_dump($cos);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set Store Id before saving option value price and title.
This line will resolve your problem:
`$v->setStoreId('0');`
Enjoy!